# How can i write join in named query?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I tried to write this Query but it throw an exception

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "doctor_searchDoctor", 
              query= "SELECT d FROM Doctor d "
                    + "WHERE ((d.englishName = :P_NAME_EN OR :P_NAME_EN = '-1' ) "
                    + "AND d.id IN (select c.doctorId from Clinic c "
                    + "JOIN DoctorSpecializations s "
                    + " where ((c.cityId = :D_CITY_ID OR :D_CITY_ID = -1 ) AND (s.specializationId = :D_SPECIALIZATION_ID OR :D_SPECIALIZATION_ID = -1))))"

  ),
})
```

while debugging the code i find the exception

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: doctor_searchDoctor

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)` in your `WHERE ((d.englishName blah` put one after `Clinic c)`

Comment: the full statement is `select c.doctorId from Clinic c JOIN DoctorSpecializations s`